# Reading what is inside DataStructure[]

Tags: dataset, code-request

In my code I end up with such data structures and I cannot see what is inside. Is there a command to open this type of data structure? I tried `\\Normal` but it does not give anything. If I copy and past it in Notepad, then I can see what is inside. but I want to see inside while in Mathematica notebook.

[image]

Comment: `ds["Elements"]` or `ds["Visualization"]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`InputForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm.html).

```
ds = CreateDataStructure["HashSet"];
ds["Insert", f[1]];

InputForm[ds]
(* DataStructure["HashSet", {"Data" -> {f[1]}}] *)
```

Or the implemented visualization feature.

```
ds["Visualization"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

```
ds = CreateDataStructure["HashSet"];

Information[ds]
```

[image]

```
ds["Insert", #] & /@ Range[12];

ds["Elements"]
```

{12, 3, 7, 11, 10, 2, 5, 4, 1, 9, 6, 8}

```
ds["Visualization"]
```

[image]